# Is it safe to use angular for isolate admin and general users?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I recently start the learning about Angularjs and I want to realise the permission control by using it.

Basically, if the user is not admin, then this user can not access to the admin page.

To realise the isolation of different users, I wrote the admin page only by using angular and like this:

```
<div class="page-header" ng-if = "main.admin">
<h1 class="center-block">User Management</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="admin.showByName(names)">Search</button>
<input type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please input the username" ng-model = "names">
<br>
<div class= "alert alert-warning" ng-show="admin.show">{{admin.err}}</div>
<br>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in admin.users | filter:admin.names" >
        <td>{{user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>
            <!-- If the user in the table is admin, the delete function will be unavailable -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show = "!user.admin" ng-click="admin.deleteUser(user.username)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<div ng-show="!main.admin">
<div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied! You have no permission to access this page</div>
```

The values of "main.admin" are only true and false. If the value is false, this page will not allow general users to access. But is it safe enough that only take measure on front end?

Comment: "But is it safe enough that only take measure on front end?" No

Comment: **NO**. All it takes to show the delete button is a simple `javascript:main.admin=true;` in the address bar. As a quick rule of thumb, everything client-side is eye-candy and the real security goes into the server-side.